# How to create popup same as wordpress popup feature

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery, ajax, javascript

I wants to include a popup window which is same like wordpress popup. 
Like if we click on the wordpress editor's link button it will open a popup window. 
I wants to create same like that.

[image]

[image: To click on the perticular voucher link it should opne a popup dialog box...]

Answer (score 1):

That's called [Thickbox](http://codex.wordpress.org/ThickBox). Since you give no clue what you want to use it for, you'll have to figure out the rest for yourself...